# tinymce getcontent for full html without filters applied

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, wysiwyg

I would like to retrieve the html contents of the tinymce area, but without the cleanup and the filters applied. How can I do that? For example, newlines are removed from the html source with this call, but I want to keep them.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Function call I have been testing in chrome:

```
console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'raw' }));
console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way using jQuery:

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
var content = $(ed.getBody).html();
```

Be aware that there may be some tinymce internal markers (spans) inside the content.

Comment: Thanks, works nice. I guess I can use tinymce.get(0) as most of the time there is only 1 tinymce.

Comment: this is correct in case there is only one editor instance you may also use tinymce.editors[0]

Comment: or just `tinymce.activeEditor`

Comment: nearly correct, but keep in mind that tinymce.activeEditor will be null if the user has not already clicked into the editor